# Based on ComboBox selection, change another ComboBox to TextBox using DataTrigger inside DataGrid CellTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, datagrid, datatrigger

I have one DataGrid where I am using CellTemplate to define various Data columns.
Like below

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Movie Source" Width="*">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <ComboBox x:Name="cbMovieSource" Width="100" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MovieSources, Mode=Twoway}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MovieSourceSelected, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
              </ComboBox>
           </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Now, I have 3/4 data columns in that DataGrid, Based on one Data column '**Movie Source**'- ComboBox's value
" **Manual Entry**", I have to change another Data column '**Movie Hall**' ComboBox into TextBox to allow user enter data. I have used Data trigger to do that.

Problem is --

1. While loading page initially its showing blank instead of default ComboBox -'**Movie Hall**'.
2. And while I am changing **Movie Source** ComboBox's value to
   "Manual    Entry" its not changing **Movie Hall** ComboBox into TextBox but if I click in
   that blank space    TextBox appearing.

I am using Observable Collection for Item source and data loading is not a problem.
But how I will get initially ComboBox but after selecting certain value from ComboBox, into TextBox is the issue here.

My Data trigger code is like below -

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Movie Hall" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="av:ContentControl" >
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbMovieSource, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="cbMovieHall" Width="120" 
                                                      ItemsSource="{Binding MovieHalls, Mode=Twoway}" 
                                                      SelectedItem="{Binding MovieHallsSelected, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">      
                                            </ComboBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MovieSourceSelected}" Value ="Manual Entry">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Width="120"  Visibility="Visible" 
                                                Text="{Binding DataContext.TextA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
       </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Initial Loading

[image]

After selecting value
[image]

After clicking on blank space under Movie Hall header-

[image]

Comment: I think you only need one DataTrigger, the second one. Use the Setter from the first DataTrigger by itself in the Style (this will be the default), and then have the Style.Triggers section with just the second DataTrigger.

Comment: If you remove first data trigger part then also your output will be same. First data trigger is where you should look thats the reason your combo box not coming

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville Can you please give some pseudo code on how I can achieve it using only one Trigger, I am not clear about - "have the Triggers section with just the second trigger"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think now issue is not in any xaml code written here, everything is just fine with DataTrigger, CellTemplate etc. Because you mentioned after clicking its changing means trigger working but **UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged** not working that's why Trigger is firing after manual click.

You also mentioned all other columns and this column also working fine with Data population that means all your ComboBox columns are having item source with collection which is declared in mvvm style, **INotifyPropertyChanged**. And I see in comment that selected property is string and item source is collection of string.

You have not wrote any c# code for those properties but with the problem I am assuming you have observable collections with data class not direct string collection.
Please make sure your c# code is like below in **ViewModel** class -

```
 private ObservableCollection<MovieData> _dataGridCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<MovieData> DataGridCollection 
    {
          get => _dataGridCollection;
          set
          {
              var changed = DataGridCollection != value;
              if (changed)
              {
                  _dataGridCollection = value;
                  NotifyPropertyChanged($"DataGridCollection ");
               }
           }
    }
```

And **Model class** like below -

```
 Public class MovieData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _movieSourceSelected;
        public string MovieSourceSelected
        {
            get => _movieSourceSelected;
            set
            {
               _movieSourceSelected = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("MovieSourceSelected");
             }
        }
    }
```

And for Xaml part, @Étienne Laneville wrote excellent code there, nothing is wrong in that part but still for answer completion adding to his answer with few minor modifications like Direct Visibility set in control itself and again inside style setter will prevent data trigger to work properly and **Grid** to **StackPanel** and **Hidden** to **Collapsed** as Hidden always occupies the space and StackPanel puts controls with **VerticalOrientation** default with one control after another not with same space, which is required here and Grid will put both control in same place..

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Movie Hall" Width="*">
    <av:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ComboBox Width="120"     
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"                                  
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MovieHalls, Mode=Twoway}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding MovieHallsSelected, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <ComboBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MovieSourceSelected,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                         Value="Manual Entry">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ComboBox.Style>
                </ComboBox>
                 <TextBox Width="120"                                                   
                          Text="{Binding DataContext.TextA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=av:DataGridRow}}">
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MovieSourceSelected,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                         Value="Manual Entry">
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility"  Value="Visible" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Edit after answer acceptance :Long story short, your ComboBox was not changing into TextBox because your trigger was not firing automatically. And your trigger was not firing automatically because your UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged was not working. And UpdateSourceTrigger was not working because your c# code was missing INotifyPropertyChanged implementation with that bind property of Selected Item of Source ComboBox.

Comment: MovieSourceSelected property was missing INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, only Observable collection had that implementation, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need one DataTrigger, the second one. Use the Setter from the first DataTrigger by itself in the Style (this will be the default), and then have the Style.Triggers section with just the second DataTrigger:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="av:ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="cbMovieHall"
                                            Width="120"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding MovieHalls, Mode=Twoway}"
                                            SelectedItem="{Binding MovieHallsSelected, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MovieSourceSelected}"
                                        Value="Manual Entry">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox Width="120"
                                                    Visibility="Visible"
                                                    Text="{Binding DataContext.TextA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The first Setter in the Style will be applied by default. Then, if the DataTrigger condition is met, the Setter in that DataTrigger will also be applied, overwriting the first Setter and, in this case, setting the ContentTemplate to the DataTemplate with a TextBox in it.

You can also simplify things by having the ComboBox and TextBox handle hiding themselves based on the DataTrigger instead of using a ContentControl:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Movie Hall"
                        Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ComboBox Width="120"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MovieHalls, Mode=Twoway}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding MovieHallsSelected, Mode=Twoway, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <ComboBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MovieSourceSelected}"
                                                Value="Manual Entry">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                            Value="Hidden" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ComboBox.Style>
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBox Width="120"
                            Visibility="Visible"
                            Text="{Binding DataContext.TextA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}">
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Hidden" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MovieSourceSelected}"
                                                Value="Manual Entry">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                            Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This XAML has a ComboBox that is Visible by default and set to Hidden when `MovieSourceSelected` is `Manual Entry`. The TextBox is Hidden by default and set to Visible with `Manual Entry`.

Regarding the Binding used for your Movie Source ComboBox, make sure it uses  `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` if you are using a String as your Dependency Property:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding MovieSourceSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Some option" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Manual Insertion" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Some other option" />
</ComboBox>
```

As a side note, you should not have to name your ComboBoxes (`cboMovieSource` and `cbMovieHall`) since they are working with bindings. You'd name them if you needed to access them in code-behind but from your XAML it doesn't look like you need to.

Comment: Thanks for code, but with this trigger not working. Only ComboBox showing.

Comment: Let me apply your edited answer. Thanks again. I can feel its almost answer.

Comment: @Strange check out the alternative approach where you simply control the TextBox and ComboBox visibility using the DataTrigger.

Comment: @
Étienne Laneville

@Étienne Laneville

Its almost working. Two issue were there. With <Grid> controls were placed upon each other and with Hidden it was overriding means both were visible.
So I have modified <Grid> to <StackPanel> and Hidden to Collapsed. Job almost done here.
Now 1st ComboBox selection changed is not notifying other ComboBox so trigger not firing need to click in that place after value changed , so I feel one Selection changed event will solve the issue. But I am trying to avoid xaml.cs code behind events here. But anyway thanks your code resolved almost 90 % issue.

Comment: @Strange the Setters are reversed, the ComboBox is Visible by default and the TextBox is Hidden by default. Both should never show at the same time.

Comment: Not exactly showing but with Hidden it was occupying space and same space and then it was not working. With Collapsed its resolved now. But now I think I need to think of some interaction event trigger implementation for this selection changed event for combobox to fire the trigger.

Comment: @Strange check the ComboBox example I added in my answer

Comment: yes property is string and collection of string. I tried selected value & path instead of selected item but only difference is its shows the default value as selected while loading, in case of selected item it does not select value automatically.

Comment: But whatever I told initially my problem with trigger in my question, that after I click only then triggers firing and textbox coming, with your version of code also same happening, after click only textbox happening.
I am trying to find out reason, anyhow datagrid rendering is slow, and its affecting heavily with custom celltemplate may be , not very sure. Same data trigger code works just fine outside data grid' cell template.  Strange issue. Anyhow thanks for your effort and help.